# How to append the timestamp of a process to the name of a file in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, mv

I have a directory `/home/user/ingest/` which has many files inside it with varying sizes. I need to move every file inside this folder into `/home/user/ingest/inbox` every two minutes. There might be a situation where the first file might take more than 2 mins to move into `/home/user/ingest/inbox`. In which case when its moving the second file, it SHOULDN'T take the first file as well. Which is why I thought to append the timestamp to the name of files at the time of moving. Is there anyway to do this in shell scripting?

And I also understand that usingh crontab might help me in scheduling the execution of the shell script every two minutes. I have a basic idea of cron but for my particular requirement, how can I check whether the file is being loved every two minutes or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)

for f in /home/user/ingest/*
do
   if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      name=$(basename "$f")
      mv $f /home/user/ingest/inbox/${name}_${TIMESTAMP}
   fi
done
```

The `${TIMESTAMP}` is the number of seconds since the epoch (Jan 1970). The for loop iterates through everything in the `/home/user/ingest/` directory, and the if statement checks to see if the file is a *regular file* (not directory, not symlink), and then the file is moved to `/home/user/ingest/inbox/` with the timestamp appended to the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Worked beautifully!